# Check in code if email in ParseUser was verified or not?

Tags: java, android, email, parse-platform, email-verification

I use parse.com as a backend service for my app. Therefore I wrote a signup/login section to my app, where :
+ I can enter a new user-email + password
+ and logout and login over and over with those credentials.

Up to here, everything works very fine. New added users-emails get a verification request from parse.com. And they are marked with a boolean  `emailVeryfied = true` if the activation link was clicked.

But how would I notice that in my Android app? The `ParseUser` object does not have a

`boolean isVerified = ParseUser.isEmailVerfied()` object??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ParseUser does not have method to check if email is verified or not but you can fetch this value by giving the key name in get method. Use this code:

```
 ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
 currentUser.get("emailVerified");
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to REsend an activation email?

Comment: Set the email field again to user object and call save method.